# Ask about the grub by having 2 ubuntus installed (18.04 LTS) and windows

Tags: 18.04

I want to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS 2 times and windows, I have a ssd of ~240 gb and an hdd of ~ 900 gb and I wanted to install a ubuntu in the ssd and another one in the hdd alongside windows. I have a question before installing them which is that in the group at the time of having 2 ubuntus and Windows installed I can do something that leaves me as first the last one I have used?. Thx

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you are asking. You can have multiple OSes on your system spread over many disks (*I have one test system with 8 Ubuntu's spread over 3 drives; windows is just another OS*)  and you can have have `grub` favor one over the others, or default to the last used (*though I've not used that option in years*) but leaves you with first last one??? I don't follow

Comment: Thanks for reply, what I mean is that in the grub you have the 3 Os if I used windows for the last time that the first option in the group is windows, if I used the Ubuntu "A" that the first option in the grub be for launch the Ubuntu "A" and so on. @guiverc

Comment: I've only had it boot the last-used (*as stated years ago though*) OR a favored (preferred) option (*my preference in recent years*).

Comment: @MitsworthSCZD The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.